# convert qgis feature to layer in qgis with python

Tags: intersection, qgis

I have 2 layers and I want to intersect one layer with one specific feature with other feature. But I cant convert the qgis.Feature to layer.
Then I want to intersect this layers(layer1 and sublayer(of layer2) and the result be layer too.
I try this code

```
canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
layers = canvas.layers()
layer1 = canvas.layer(0)
layer2 = canvas.layer(1)
layer = QgsVectorLayer('C:\Users\Folder\myshapefile.shp','myshafile', 'ogr')
selection = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression('"fid"=555'))
overlayAnalyzer=QgsOverlayAnalyzer()
overlayAnalyzert.intersects(layer1,selection,r"C:\output.sha")
```

How to convert feature of selection to layer , so, tointersect layer1 with selection_layer and this to return a new layer